# how can I color-swizzle shader to convert the RGBA to BGRA

Tags: ios, opengl

I was to do the swizzling as, if I try to convert it later then it seems to be very slow.
Any examples?

I am using this to make video of my application

I currently use

```
 glReadPixels(x, y, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

and it returns me data in RGBA format, I need to convert it to BGRA how can I do it efficiently?

Comment: What? your question doesn't make any sense? Though `outColor.rgba = outColor.bgra;` in the Shader I guess...

Answer (score 4):

You know there is a BGRA format, which glReadPixels can deliver:

```
glReadPixels(x, y, width, height, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

And in fact it's recommended you use BGRA for reading pixels, since this is the ordering most GUI systems use internally, thus saving a conversion step.